# Getting question marks and now exceeding tex capacity after trying to add reference

Tags: bibliographies, texmaker

I'm using TexMaker, and I'm fairly new this using latex.

Some time ago, I wrote a report in LaTeX. If I wanted to reference something I would type in `\cite{blah}` (assuming blah was referenced in the `bibfile`), then I would run quick build. Sometimes I would get a question mark where the reference should be, but I would randomly run the other options like `Dvi->PS` or `BibTeX`, then I would run `Quick Builder` again and it would work.

This time it doesn't seem to work. When running `Quick Builder` it gives  question marks as usual, then when I randomly run the other options, and then run quick builder again, I get an error now:

`! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].\hmode@bgroup ->\leavevmode\bgroup
on line 43`

Can anyone help? I've included a zip file of my document at this 
[download link](http://expirebox.com/download/bf857140ca7689fa0866f5a0c959e75e.html).
The file with this issue is called Report_Template

Comment: I'm not familiar with TexMaker. Just one thought, there is nothing random to be done here: you should run `pdflatex > bibtex > pdflatex`. You files worked fine when I ran as instructed.

Comment: I tried this just now but I got the tex capacity error again

Comment: I get no problems with it either. BTW: Please learn NOT to use ``\\`` in the text. It has no placs there (this is why you get so many `underfull ... badless 10000` warnings. Mark new paragraphs with a blank line in the code. And yes paragraph indentation *is* your friend.

Comment: The file I am using is called Report_Template if that matters? 

(Not the test file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at it again, and I do get problems after removing all the aux files and recompiling. It seems the `harvard` package does not handle URLs really well.

Compiles just fine if I add this after the `harvard` package.

```
\usepackage{url}
\renewcommand{\harvardurl}[1]{\textbf{URL:} \url{#1}}
```

The problem is that you have an URL with `_` in it. The `harvard` does not protect the URLs.

But I never get a `TeX capacity exceeded` error

Comment: Thank you, I've added the two lines. So as an example I added

\cite{equipment}, then ran pdflatex, then bibtex (got a weird message that wasnt a red error, it was black) then pdflatex, then quick builder, and it seems to work now